# renombrar observaciones según intervalos R

Tags: r, funciones, condiciones, else

Tengo unos datos numéricos que he de renombrar con tres argumentos (bajo, medio y alto) según el intervalo en el que se encuentren.

Para saber que intervalos tomar uso los cuantiles:

```
quantile(df$cons_conf_id)

   0%   25%   50%   75%  100% 
-50.8 -42.7 -41.8 -36.4 -26.9
```

Y creo una función para que renombre las variables dependiendo del intervalo en el que se encuentren:

```
conf_idx <- function(indice_confianza){
  
  if(indice_confianza > -50.8 & indice_confianza < (-42.7-41.8)/2){
    
    print("low")
    
    }else if(indice_confianza > (-42.7-41.8)/2 & indice_confianza < (-41.8-36.4)/2){
      
      print("medium")
      
      }else{
        
        print("high")
}
}
```

Pero al ejecutarlo me sale este error, que debe ser el más básico, pero he intentado aplicar un bucle while y no he conseguido que se aplique sobre todas las observaciones de la variable:

```
conf_idx(df$cons_conf_id)
[1] "high"
Warning messages:
1: In if (indice_confianza > -50.8 & indice_confianza < (-42.7 - 41.8)/2) { :
  la condición tiene longitud > 1 y sólo el primer elemento será usado
2: In if (indice_confianza > (-42.7 - 41.8)/2 & indice_confianza <  :
  la condición tiene longitud > 1 y sólo el primer elemento será usado
```

Cómo puedo aplicar la función para transformar las observaciones numéricas en toda la columna?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

creo que una manera mas simple pero efectiva es utilizar lo siguiente:

```
library(tidyverse)

df = df %>%
  mutate(
    nivel = case_when(
      indice_confianza > 50.8 & indice_confianza < (-42.7 - 41.8) / 2 ~ "low",
      indice_confianza > (-42.7-41.8)/2 & indice_confianza < (-41.8-36.4)/2 ~ "medium",
      TRUE ~ "high"
    )
  )
```

Creamos la variable nivel y luego utilizamos el case_when que es la forma vectorizada del if, ojo con los mayores y menores estrictos, yo los mantuve tal cual los pusiste en tu codigo.

Otra forma también que es muy efectiva es usando la funcion cut

```
df %>%
  mutate(nivel = cut(
    indice_confianza,
    breaks = c(50.8, (-42.7-41.8)/2, (-41.8-36.4)/2, Inf),
    c("low", "medium", "high"),
    right = FALSE
  ))
```

En este caso tambien creamos la variable nivel la cual tomara valores low, medium y hight en base a los 3 intervalos que definimos en la sentencia breaks, ojo nuevamente con la sentencia right = false , la cual indica si quieres los intervalos abiertos o cerrados hacia la derecha.

Espero te sea de utilidad alguno de los dos métodos planteados

Comment: Muchas gracias!! Use un sapply para usar la funcion sobre toda la columna y funcionó, pero esta manera deja un código mas limpio. Gracias de nuevo y un saludo.